# Not able to add another table in sqlite database in android studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I created several tables in the `application` and all worked well. after that I am trying to add one more table with the same approach but it always gives following error

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: patients_record (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM patients_record
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>   Here is the query of the table.

```
 private static final String PATIENT_TABLE_CREATE = "create table if not exists patients_record( patientId text primary key not null, "
            + "patientFirstName text not null, patientLastName text not null, patientDepartment text not null, patientDoctorId text not null, patientRoom text not null );";
```

I added the string to `onCreate()` of `Database` Handler with other `tables` that are created previously.

Comment: Uninstall app and Install again

Comment: Increase DB version.

Comment: share DbHandler class

Comment: @RonakThakkar `Uninstall app ` is not good approach.

Comment: Increasing DB version worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have stucked with the same situation where i was adding a new column in my existing table, I solved this problem by changing the Database version number variable, just increase you DB version and build your project again and try.

**Reason :** When you first create table the sqlite calls `onCreate` method after that it never calls it again until you call your `onUpgrade` method, so to make changes inside you DB just `increase your DB version` that will cal `onUpgrade` method.

Comment: This method depends upon the `onUpgrade` method being implemented accordingly. It is only advisable to advise this method if it is known that the `onUpgrade` method will perform the necessary actions. As the question does not show the `onUpgrade` method it is impossible to say that increasing the Database Version will undoubtedly work.

Comment: alright but assuming he has implemented onupgrade and creating new tablel inside it after droping existing one

Answer (score 0):

The most usual cause is a misunderstanding in regard to when the `onCreate` methods runs automatically. Newcomers to SQLite often assume that it runs everytime an instance of the SQLiteOpenHelper subclass (often known as the DatabaseHelper) is instantiated.

However, `onCreate` is only called automatically when the Database is created. As such a simple fix, when developing an App, is to delete the database. When the App next runs the `onCreate` method will be invoked and create the amended structure.

- Deleting the App's data will delete the database as it is part of the App's data.
- Uninstalling the App will also delete the App's data.
- Often the 'onUpgrade' method will contain code that DROPS the tables and then calls the `onCreate` method. The `onUpgrade` method is invoked when the Database version is increased.

Note that using any of the 3 methods above will result in some data being lost.